# How to get javascript callback to work

Tags: javascript

I have started to learn Javascript recently, and since I'm coming from a Windows development world, I'm having a hard time accepting some JS techniques..

I'm trying to load several pictures at the same time in to a page using a FileReader. I know I need to use asynchronous callbacks, but it seems that I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
function loadFile(file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(file) {
        var output = document.createElement('input');
        output.type = 'image';
        output.classList.add('image-responsive');
        output.src = reader.result;

        var x = document.getElementById('OrigName');
        x.appendChild(output);
    }
    loadFile(file, callback);

}

for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
    var file = evt.target.files[i];
    loadFile(file);
}
```

Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: We could help if you tell us the specific problem you are encountering

Comment: `"Can someone please help me fix this?"` - What's wrong with it?  What needs to be corrected?  And why are recursing on `loadFile()` with the same arguments, isn't that just an infinite recursion?

Comment: This code full of bugs, why do you create an `input` and place to it `src` read image? And actually where do you call file reading?

Comment: You are calling `loadFile(file, callback);` within the loadFile function, this is a never ending loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood how callbacks work. You probably want something more like this:

```
function loadFile(file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(file) {
        var output = document.createElement('input');
        output.type = 'image';
        output.classList.add('image-responsive');
        output.src = reader.result;

        var x = document.getElementById('OrigName');
        x.appendChild(output);
        return callback(output);
    }

}

evt.target.files.forEach(function (file) {
    loadFile(file, function (output) {
        console.log(output);
    }); 
})
```

This will `console.log` the output once each file is loaded. You should note though that the files may be loaded in a different order to the order in the array.

Comment: That worked, i just had to add reader.readAsDataURL(file); after reader.onload() call. and change forEach loop to for i=0..., because for some reason browser returned "forEach is not a function" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, the code isn't correct, for a start you are calling your load function:

```
loadFile(file);
```

In the for loop and not specifying a call back. Therefore it's going to be undefined when you want to use it. I'm assuming another function should be made to sendFile and that may be the call back. 
Overall the code needs some work. Think about the problem again and refactor the code, perhaps using Jasmine to write some unit tests to build the code up step by step.